# Trouble showing data on Gridview in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, gridview, datatable

I have been having trouble displaying data on a gridview on ASP.NET.

Here's my gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="grvConsumptions" runat="server" AllowSorting="true" 
    AllowPaging="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" RowStyle-CssClass="txtB" 
    DataKeyNames="idConsumption" PageSize="30" Width="100%" CssClass="borders"
    HeaderStyle-CssClass="subT" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="txtA" 
    onpageindexchanging="grvConsumptions_PageIndexChanging" 
    onsorting="grvConsumptions_Sorting">
    <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" CssClass="subT" />

    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="ltNoInformationFound">
            No Data Found
        </asp:Literal>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>

    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" ReadOnly="true" DataField="idConsumption" SortExpression="idConsumption" HtmlEncode="False" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="No. Venta" ReadOnly="true" DataField="stationSaleNumber" SortExpression="stationSaleNumber" HtmlEncode="False" />

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Trans">
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center">
            </ItemStyle>

            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="imgPayment" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/icons/aro.gif">
                </asp:Image>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Tarjeta" ReadOnly="true" DataField="cardCode" SortExpression="cardCode" HtmlEncode="False" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Fecha" ReadOnly="true" DataField="dateCreated" SortExpression="dateCreated" HtmlEncode="False" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Litros" ReadOnly="true" DataField="quantity" SortExpression="quantity" DataFormatString="{0:0.000}" HtmlEncode="False" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Descripción" ReadOnly="true" ItemStyle-Width="5%" DataField="description" SortExpression="description" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Precio Unitario" ReadOnly="true" DataField="price" SortExpression="price" HtmlEncode="False"/>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Importe" ReadOnly="true" DataField="total" SortExpression="total" HtmlEncode="False"/>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Kms" ReadOnly="true" DataField="mileage" SortExpression="mileage" HtmlEncode="False"/>
    </Columns>

    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
    <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
    <EditRowStyle CssClass="txtB" />
    <EmptyDataRowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="tboxCombo" ForeColor="DarkGoldenrod" BorderWidth="0px" />
    <RowStyle CssClass="txtB" />
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="subT" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="txtA" />
</asp:GridView>
```

and this is a simple method that I used.

```
DataTable dtConsumptions = GetData();
grvConsumptions.DataSource = dtConsumptions;
grvConsumptions.DataBind();
```

To my knowledge, I can't find a way to debug and find out why data is nos displayed on the gridview (It always shows the label No Data Found).

I already double checked that the DataTable has data indeed, and that all columns that the gridview requests are present in the datatable's columns.

How can I fix this issue or find an exception of why is not displaying data??

Comment: **For Debugging:** remove `Columns` tag and everything inside it. `AutoGenerateColumns="false"` to `AutoGenerateColumns="true"` Then what do you see?

Comment: at what event you are binding the data?

Comment: nothing... still No Data Found

Comment: Where are you binding the GridView? Page_Load?

Comment: apparentely I use that method When Page Load, and it shows No Data Found (because at that moment the datatable doesnt get any rows, so it's correct so far), then I have a button where I can do a more advanced search and when I press it (it returns a datatable with rows, and it does pass by that method), however it does not reload the gridview (I noticed that when I decided to get rid of the method at the Page Load), so apparentely it only does not reload the gridview when I press the button =S

Comment: wait, I figured it out (I still need a little bit of research though)

I have an update panel:

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upd" runat="server">
 <ContentTemplate>
  <asp:Label ID="lblTotalAmount" runat="server">
  </asp:Label>
 </ContentTemplate>
 <Triggers>
  <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnFilter" EventName="Click" />
 </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

and apparentely when I press the button, it only reloads the label, but it does not reload the gridview...
when I got rid of the update panel, it worked, the gridview was reloaded

Comment: Could you post that as an answer?  I think it oculd help others with the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wait, I figured it out (I still need a little bit of research though) I have an update panel:          and apparentely when I press the button, it only reloads the label, but it does not reload the gridview... when I got rid of the update panel, it worked, the gridview was reloaded

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RowDataBound event` , and bind your datas on your server side with code c#;

loop about your rows and debug.

LInk : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx